# Bundle Osgi is invalid

Tags: java, osgi

I new start osgi.. my project is running java application but not running osgi .
the problem:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator osgi.Activator for
bundle osgi is invalid at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:172) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: osgi.Activator cannot be cast
to org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
  ... 12 more Root exception: java.lang.ClassCastException:
osgi.Activator cannot be cast to org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230) at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Comment: Code..Code ..Code !!!

Comment: Argh! Java stack trace on my entire screen. Can't even look at it now. Somebody change the page please! (Seriously! You onle need the first few lines and add some code!)

Comment: Please use code blocks instead of blockquote to show stack traces.

Comment: @ItayGrudev It's better to have the complete stack trace IMHO, but formatted with code blocks.

Comment: @Puce Noted and edited. ;)

Comment: Is that possible that you accidentally included the org.osgi packages into your bundle? I mean that these packages and the class files are actually in your jar file.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator osgi.Activator for
> bundle osgi is invalid at
> [...]
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: osgi.Activator cannot be cast
> to org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator at
> ```

It looks like your `osgi.Activator` class is registered as Activator but does not implement`org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator`

Comment: I resolved this problem but now I encounter the different problem problem is :   
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in deneme.Activator.start() of bundle deneme.  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/codemodel/JCodeModel

Comment: @alperenbolat if this is a different issue, consider to start a new question. Otherwise please update your question with all necessary information (code, error message, stack trace,...)

Comment: Thanks  I solve resolved all problems .. My code is running